# Resposta da API

Tags: android, api, kotlin

Estou implementando uma função Search em uma lista, quero pegar a resposta da minha API para ver se ela esta correta para o meu Search. Como posso pegar a resposta de uma fun @GET da minha API? Estou usando o Retrofit

função que quero a resposta para ver se estou recebendo corretamente para colocar no Search:

```
@GET("v2/cards?q=name:")
suspend fun getPokemonsPesquisa(@Query("q") name: String): Response<PokemonsResponse>
```

AppRetrofit:

```
private const val BASE_URL =  "https://api.pokemontcg.io/"

class AppRetrofit {
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(AppInterceptor())
    .build()

private val retrofit by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()
}
val pokemonService: API by lazy {
    retrofit.create(API::class.java)
 }

}
```

AppInterceptor:

```
class AppInterceptor : Interceptor {

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    var original = chain.request()
    val url = original.url.newBuilder()
        .addQueryParameter("api_key", BuildConfig.API_KEY).build()
    original = original.newBuilder().url(url).build()
    return chain.proceed(original)

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já que você tá usando coroutine, não precisa que o retorno do seu método @GET seja um `Response<...>`, basta ser o seu objeto `PokemonsResponse` direto. Ou seja, modifique a sua classe `API` para que o método fique assim:

```
@GET("v2/cards?q=name:")
suspend fun getPokemonsPesquisa(@Query("q") name: String): PokemonsResponse
```

Pra chamar esse método, você precisa usar aquela referência do `pokemonService` da classe `AppRetrofit` e chamar o método `getPokemonsPesquisa` nele, dentre de um escopo de coroutine. O exemplo completo depende de onde você vai chamar isso exatamente, mas pode ser algo do tipo:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    try {
        val response = pokemonService.getPokemonsPesquisa("Scorbunny")
        // use o objeto response aqui
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        // trate a exceção aqui
    }
}
```

(... nesse caso, se for chamar esse método a partir de um `ViewModel`, por exemplo)